# Testing Laravel API resources with dependency injections and custom requests

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection, phpunit, laravel-5, inversion-of-control

Type hinted route parameter does not instantiate when called from a test.

I have a Laravel API Resource `Route::apiResource('users', 'Api\UserController');`

Here's my update method in the controller:

```
public function update(UpdateUserRequest $request, User $user)
{
    //
}
```

Inside the UpdateUserRequest:

```
public function rules()
{
    dd($this->route("user"));
}
```

If I call this endpoint from Postman, I get the full `user` object back. However, if I call it from a test:

```
    $response = $this->actingAs($this->user)->
        json('POST', '/api/users/'.$this->user->id, [
            '_method' => 'PUT',
            'data' => [
                // ...
            ]
        ]);
```

I just get the string "1", not the instantiated User object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one thing that worked, and I don't know if this is the correct or the "Laravel" way of doing things is to force instantiate the model in the custom request constructor, and to bind the instance inside the test:

In the UpdateUserRequest:

```
private $user;

public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

In the Test:

```
$this->user = factory(\App\Models\User::class)->create();
$this->app->instance(\App\Models\User::class, $this->user);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by the `\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware` trait being used by your test case.

For posterity, should anyone come across this, route model binding is performed by the `\Illuminate\Routing\MiddlewareSubstituteBindings` middleware. The `WithoutMiddleware` trait therefore prevents it from running.

The base Laravel test case provides an undocumented `withoutMiddleware()` method via `/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/WithoutMiddleware` which you can use to get around this, however it may be worth noting that the lead developer of Laravel, Taylor Otwell, [recommends](https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/4677) testing with all middleware active when possible.